# Plotting data points on Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a class that is responsible for plotting data points. This class inherits from canvas.

The points need to be plotted as a 5 pixel by 5 pixel square centered, which have x and y coordinates corresponding to my height and weight data.

A vertical and horizontal line should overlay the canvas and intersect the mouse location when the data is being displayed.

So far I have this:

```
class Plotter(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master,*args,**kwargs):
        TkInter.Canvas.__init__(self, master = master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize)
        self.height = self.winfo_reqheight()
        self.width = self.winfo_reqwidth()


    def on_resize(self,event):
        wscale = float(event.width)/self.width
        hscale = float(event.height)/self.height
        self.width = event.width
        self.height = event.height
        self.config(width=self.width, height=self.height)
        self.scale("all",0,0,wscale,hscale)
```

What do I need to do in order to improve my code? I don't understand how to plot my points on 5 x 5 pixels. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have defined self._canvas, I've found that using self._canvas.create_oval(xval,yval,xval,yval,width = 5) creates a 5 x 5 pixel point at (xval, yval) on your canvas.